# Eclipse Android Boot Camp- How to modify the Ferry app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The mentor has asked that we create a simple app that allows user to enter amount of tickets and click to compute cost at a set rate of $18 for the two locations. We have been asked to outsource and research to complete the app MODIFICATION; so that tickets to (1)Cape Marie cost $20 and tickets to (2)Star Island cost $30. My code is below;

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        double costPerTicket=18.00;
        int numberOfTickets;
        double totalCost;
        String groupChoice;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final EditText tickets=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTickets);
            final Spinner group=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
            Button cost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCost);
            cost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                final TextView result=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    numberOfTickets=Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText().toString());
                    totalCost=costPerTicket * numberOfTickets;
                    DecimalFormat currency=new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                    groupChoice=group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    result.setText("Total cost for "+groupChoice +" is " +currency.format(totalCost));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: Basically, if your code is working, you go to CodeReview. I do not know if I should review your code, since that way I would be giving bad example to others.

Comment: the code and app works fine however it is set at $18 for each selected car ferry cost, we need to implement two so instead of totalCost=18 we need to make it cape marie=$20 and star island = $30. pretty clear question and we were asked to research and outsource people, sites to be able to do this isnt this is what this site is about

Comment: I was going to post the answer on the other question... please read it and if more help is needed don't be afraid to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare a spinner in your layout... once you declare the spinner you go to your Strings.xml file wich is under values folder... right there you add an array like this...

```
<string-array name="LocationArray">
    <item>Cape Marie</item>   
    <item>Star Island</item>
</string-array>
```

then you go back to your activity...

we need to create an instance of an spinner and set an adapter to the LocationArray so we can display the values... the code goes like this:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_SPINNER_ID);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and adapter code goes like this...

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.LocationArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

so in your code should go like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    double costPerTicket=18.00;
    int numberOfTickets;
    double totalCost;
    String groupChoice;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText tickets=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTickets);
        final Spinner group=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        Button cost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCost);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,  R.array.LocationArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_SPINNER_ID);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        cost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            final TextView result=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String SpinnerValue = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(SpinnerValue.equals("Cape Marie")){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   numberOfTickets=Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText().toString());
                   totalCost = 20 * numberOfTickets;
                   DecimalFormat currency=new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                   groupChoice=group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   result.setText("Total cost for "+groupChoice +" is " +currency.format(totalCost)); 
            }
             if(SpinnerValue.equals("Star Island")){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   numberOfTickets=Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText().toString());
                   totalCost = 30 * numberOfTickets;
                   DecimalFormat currency=new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                   groupChoice=group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   result.setText("Total cost for "+groupChoice +" is " +currency.format(totalCost)); 
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: WOW it is people like you who make this world a better place ;-) thumbs up with many thanks, have yourself an awesome day

Comment: glad to help... if more assistance is needed dont be afraid to ask... cheers!!

Comment: I have implemented it, well done works well I greatly appreciate your kind help now I understand I needed to if statements and to have a ArrayAdapter which we have not been taught yet...Once again Thank you greatly appreciated. When my rep goes up I will add votes

Comment: glad to hel mr. @CaseyT any further assistance or guidence thru some code feel free to ask... cheers!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could create `TicketType` object for each different ticket. Something like this:

```
public class TicketType {    
    //single ticket price, depending on JAVA version, you could try making price final
    private double price;
    //Total spent
    private double moneySpent;
    public TicketType(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    //buy tickets, returns how much it cost
    public double buy(int amount){
        double priceForAmount = amount*price;
        moneySpent+=priceForAmount;
        return priceForAmount;
    }
    //return how much money was spent during objects lifetime
    public double getMoneySpent(){
        if(moneySpent==0) ???;
        else
        return moneySpent;
    }
```

And use this very simply:

```
//probably create some class variables:
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TicketType capeMarie = new TicketType(18.0);
    TicketType startIsland = new TicketType(30.0);
    //something to switch between selection
    RadioGroup selectedType;
...

onClick(View v){
        //parse number
        TicketType selectedTicketType = null;
        int id = selectedType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        switch(id){
            case CAPE_MARIE_ID:
                selectedTicketType =capeMarie;
            break;
            case ...:...break;
        }
        double price = selectedTicketType.buy(parsedNumber);
        //show price to user
}
```

Comment: Thankyou perfect and understandable, thanks for answering the question and your time to help me and others around the world with programming, works a charm ;-)

Comment: Is there another suggestive way your knowledge and help can be implement into my code as the requirement is a spinner with two locations cape Marie and Star Island; cape marie equals $20 per ticket and Star Island $30 per ticket. User enters number of tickets, selects from spinner the location and when button is pressed it calculates the total cost?

Comment: will vote you up when i get rep too, as your answer works well too ;-)